# Write a func invert(x,p,n) that returns x with the n bits that begin at position p inverted (1 becomes 0 & vice-versa), leaving the others unchanged

Tags: c, gcc, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-xor

Is the following solution to the question correct?

My solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{
    return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) ^ ~(~0 << n);
}

int main()
{ 
    printf("%d\n", invert(6, 4, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

which prints the output `6`, the binary equivalent of `0110`.

Comment: What output do you get and what output du you expect? [Edit] your question and let us know.

Comment: No, your solution is wrong, at least because `x` is shifted. How are the positions numbered, is position 0 the LSB? What is the correct result? (I'd say it is 26, binary 00011010.)

Comment: How is `p` interpreted? Is it the 0-based index of the most significant bit, counting from bit 0 at the LSB?

Comment: Just create your mask as `mask = ((1<<n)-1) << p`, then XOR it with x.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not correct.

`x >> (p+1-n)` will shift *all* the bits of the original number, so that the most significant ones can't remain unchanged.

I'd use something like the following

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{
    int const n_bits = sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT;
    assert(p >= 0  &&  p < n_bits);
    assert(n >= 0  &&  n + p <= n_bits);
    if ( n == 0 )
        return x;
    unsigned const mask = (~0u >> (n_bits - n)) << p;

    return x ^ mask;
}
```

Comment: `(x & ~mask) | (~x & mask)` is `x ^ mask`.

Comment: Although it is asserted that `n + p < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT`, a caller could request changing all the bits starting at position 0.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1) Yeah, my bad. Thankfully [optimizers](https://godbolt.org/z/h6Px1b6se) forgive a lot nowadays. 2) Another good point.